# Flutter Firestore Server side Timestamp

Tags: dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter

I need to add a server side timestamp on new documents added to Firestore using a Flutter app. I see I am supposed to use `FieldValue.serverTimestamp` but I am not sure where to find this.

Comment: take a [look](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/13905)

Answer (score 84, accepted):

As of September 5th, the updated `cloud_firestore` v0.8.0 library now has [`FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/FieldValue/serverTimestamp.html). All is now well in the universe

Comment: Looks like this is the right answer but please add more code to show what should be the data type of the variable in which it is being stored, also how to sort by this value?

Comment: @ShajeelAfzal All those questions were not in the OP's post. You can always create a new one if you'd like those answered.

Comment: I don't know why but i get a problem with serverTimestamp(), it seems that it takes some time to write the time for server and my first snapshots have null values! Here i posted my own question about it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64287252/time-field-servertimestamp-in-cloud-firestore-returns-null-on-the-first-snapsh

Comment: @ShajeelAfzal : datatype 'dynamic' for worked in my code. is there a more suitable choice?

Answer (score 22):

'timestamp' : Timestamp.now()

**Timestamp.now()** is part of cloud_firestore;

---

**Example**
[image]
Screenshot showing that the library is imported from cloud_firestore, and creates `a server-generated timestamp in the written data.` [Docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/FieldValue/serverTimestamp.html)

Comment: Works like a charm in 2019

Comment: I believe Timestamp.now() returns the timestamp in the client machine's time, not the server side timestamp.

Comment: this replaces FieldValue.serverTimestamp() which has been depricated

Comment: The documentation now leads to `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` This `Timestamp.now()` returns a client DateTime in microseconds

Comment: So what's difference between `Timestamp.now()` and `DateTime.now()`?

Answer (score 18):

Expanding on @spongyboss' answer (which works as of April 2020) by adding sample usage:

```
_firestore.collection('messages').add({
                      'text': messageText,
                      'sender': loggedInUser.email,
                      'created': FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
                  });
```

'created' will be stored as a `timestamp`

Sample sorting:

```
_firestore.collection('messages')
          .orderBy('created', descending: false)
          .snapshots()
```

Comment: This value is not usable if you want to access it in offline mode, afaik.

Comment: `orderBy` will not work until you create index by following index path displayed in vscode console. I have run that index url given by firebase and `orderby` worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using a model class to set the data, then you should create a dynamic variable with some name. For mine it was 'createdDate'.

```
class Products {
  Products({
    this.data,
    this.createdDate,
  });

  List<ProductItems>? data;
  dynamic createdDate;

  factory Products.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Products(
        data: List<ProductItems>.from(json["data"].map((x) => ProductItems.fromJson(x))),
        createdDate: json["createdDate"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "data": List<dynamic>.from(data!.map((x) => x.toJson())),
        "createdDate": createdDate
      };
}

class ProductItems {
  String? id;
  String? name;
  int? price;
  int? quantity;

  ProductItems({
    this.price,
    this.quantity,
    this.name,
    this.id,
  });

  ProductItems.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    price = json['price'];
    quantity = json['quantity'];
    name = json['name'];
    id = json['id'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['price'] = price;
    data['quantity'] = quantity;
    data['name'] = name;
    data['id'] = id;
    return data;
  }
}
```

And during setting the data to firestore,

```
    final CollectionReference _cart = _firestore.collection('cart');

    final _cartReference = _cart.withConverter<Products>(
      fromFirestore: (snapshot, _) => Products.fromJson(snapshot.data()!),
      toFirestore: (userModel, _) => userModel.toJson(),
    );

    await _cartReference.doc(auth?.uid).set(Products(
      data: productList.data,
      createdDate: FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    ));
```