# Get the latest data from Firestore database into Flutter App

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Right now my app can send the user location to Firestore database continuously. but I can't find a way to access **only the last location data** sent to Firestore so that I can retrieve it and plot it into the map.

i am using below method to send data into firestore.

```
  _addGeoPoint(LatLng myloc) {
    GeoFirePoint myLocation =
        geo.point(latitude: myloc.latitude, longitude: myloc.longitude);
    firestore
        .collection('locations')
        .add({'busName': 'WP9885','routeNo':'155','position': myLocation.data});
  }
```

[image: FireStore structure]

Comment: you can use StreamBuilder to stream live data from firebase into your app

Comment: What do you mean by the 'last location'

Comment: @Taio I meant the latest location

Comment: @ShaileshBhokare i look into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore doesn't have a concept of "last" or "most recent" data.  You should [store a server timestamp field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50907151/flutter-firestore-server-side-timestamp) in your document if you want to add a sense of time to the documents in your collection.

If you have a timestamp field in each document, then you can query for the most recently added document using code similar to this:

```
firestore
  .collection("locations")
  .orderBy("location", "desc")
  .limit(1)
```

Comment: So what u are saying is whenever the data is being added into firestore, i should save a timestamp with it. then write a query that sort it based on that time and retrieve it.

Comment: Yes, that's what you'll need to do.

Comment: will it be efficient for a tracking application?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  If you have a new question, please post it separately.